# To append comma separated value no duplicates in mysql update Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing table data as comma separated values like this

```
id    name       fk_id

1      abc       2,4,6
2       def      2,7,8
```

Now, I want to use CASE WHEN or some function in Update Query of MySQL which updates the field if no duplicate value:

For example, same value for fk_id then ignores else update like if 10 for id 1 then update but if 7 for id 2 then ignore

```
id    name       fk_id

1      abc       2,4,6,10
2       def      2,7,8
```

I tried the following code:

```
if(
            find_in_set($fk_id,fk_id),
            fk_id, 
            CONCAT_WS(',', fk_id, $fk_id)
          )
```

But not working.

Comment: Stop using comma-separated data in a database column and these problems go away.

Comment: The problem is the order of the concat_ws arguments, but for me the problem is the whole architecture ! why would you use comma separated when the column is FK !!! If it is FK and the relation is many to many you should insert a record for each combination like:
1 abc 2
1 abc 4
1 abc 6
and if you want to get a result set for all values corresponding to id then use group by in your queries, by this at least you can easily deal with where conditions

Answer (score 3):

Just update your code like as

```
set fk_id = if(find_in_set($fk_id,fk_id),
            fk_id, 
            CONCAT(fk_id, ',', $fk_id)
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "
UPDATE `test` 
SET `fk_id` = CONCAT(fk_id, ',','" . $fk_id . "') 
WHERE `fk_id` REGEXP ',?(" . $fk_id . "),?'
";
```

NOTE : REGEXP is not the best option when it comes to speed.